# How to stop reflecting values on table column filed values?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am working with jQuery table with some calculations and with results it gave me some warning messages and i want that if there is any warning message of right side of any row of the table then it should just show me the value "BULK" below table under id="result" and that should not reflect with another values of table.
 here is the site link : http://sea.studioscue.in/test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .widtot, .perm, .tottot, .vol, .tot, .vols, .heights, .acts, .heitot').prop('readonly', true);
        var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

        $tblrows.each(function (index) {
            var $tblrow = $(this);
            $tblrow.find('.width, .height, .carton, .perm, .act').on('change', function () {
                var carton = $tblrow.find("[name=carton][type=number][min=0]").val();
                 var height = $tblrow.find("[name=height][type=number][min=0]").val();
                  var width = $tblrow.find("[name=width][type=number][min=0]").val();
                  var act = $tblrow.find("[name=act][type=number][min=0]").val();
                   var perm = $tblrow.find("[name=perm]").val();

                var subTotal = parseFloat(height*0.01, 10) * parseInt(carton, 10);
                var cartons =parseInt(carton, 10);

                 if (!isNaN(cartons)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.carton').val(cartons.toFixed(0));
                    var cartonTotal = 0;

                    $(".carton").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseInt($(this).val());
                        cartonTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.cartontot').val(cartonTotal.toFixed(0));
                 }           
                 if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.perm').val(subTotal.toFixed(5));
                    var grandTotal = 0;

                    $(".perm").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(5));
                 }
                    $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(5));
                 var length = $(this).val();
                var lngthOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'length') ? length : false;

                var width = $(this).val();
                var wdthOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'width') ? width : false;

                var height = $(this).val();
                  var hightOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'height') ? height : false;

                var carton = $(this).val();
                var cartonOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'carton') ? carton : false;

                var act = $(this).val();
                var actOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'act') ? act : false;


                if (grandTotal > 7 && lngthOnly < 590 && lngthOnly < 1201 && wdthOnly < 235 && hightOnly < 238 && hightOnly < 269) {
                    $('#result').html('FCL');
                } else if (grandTotal < 7 && lngthOnly < 590 && lngthOnly < 1201 && wdthOnly < 235 && hightOnly < 238 && hightOnly < 269) {
                    $('#result').html('LCL');
                }           
                else if ((grandTotal < 7 || grandTotal > 7) && (lngthOnly > 590 || lngthOnly > 1201 || wdthOnly > 235 || hightOnly > 238))
                { 
                $('#result').html('BULK');
                }

                var height = $(this).val();
                var hightOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'height') ? height : false;
                var subCalc  =  parseFloat(height);
                if (!isNaN(subCalc)) {
                $tblrow.find('.calcheight').val(subCalc.toFixed(5));
                var calcTotal = 0;
                $(".calcheight").each(function () {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                calcTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                });
                $('.heitot').val(calcTotal.toFixed(5));
                }
                var sp = subCalc;
                hightOnly  =  parseFloat(hightOnly);
                if(hightOnly > 238 && hightOnly < 269) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td.error').text("Cargo won't fit in 20STD and 40STD Containers, change the mode to bulk");
                }   else if(hightOnly > 269){
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td.error').text("Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk");
                } else if(hightOnly < 269) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td.error').text('');
                }
                var width = $(this).val();
                var wdthOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'width') ? width : false;
                var subCalcwidth  =  parseFloat(width);
                if (!isNaN(subCalcwidth)) {
                $tblrow.find('.calcwidth').val(subCalcwidth.toFixed(5));
                var calcwidthTotal = 0;
                $(".calcwidth").each(function () {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                calcwidthTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                });
                $('.widtot').val(calcwidthTotal.toFixed(5));
                }
                var spwidth = subCalcwidth;
                wdthOnly  =  parseFloat(wdthOnly);
                if (wdthOnly > 235) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td.errorwidth').text("Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk");
                }    else if (wdthOnly < 235) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td.errorwidth').text('');
                }
             }); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
<table id="tblProducts">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Packages</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Cartons</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Cm Width</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Cm Height</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Act Kilos</strong></td>
        <td><strong>M3</strong></td>
       <td><strong>Warning Messages</strong></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" style="width:120px" /></td>
        <td ><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="carton" value="0" name="carton" min="0" maxlength="5" style="width:70px"></td>
        <td><input type="number" onKeyPress="return AllowOnlyNumbers(event);" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  class="width" value="0" min="0" name="width" maxlength="5" style="width:110px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="height" value="0" min="0" name="height" maxlength="5" style="width:110px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" onKeyPress="return AllowOnlyNumbers(event);" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  class="act" value="0" min="0" name="act" maxlength="5" style="width:90px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="perm" value="" name="perm" style="width:80px"/></td>
        <td class="error" style="color:red"></td> <td class="errorwidth" style="color:red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Second" name="pnm" style="width:120px" /></td>
        <td ><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="carton" value="0" name="carton" min="0" maxlength="5" style="width:70px"></td>
        <td><input type="number" onKeyPress="return AllowOnlyNumbers(event);" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  class="width" value="0" min="0" name="width" maxlength="5" style="width:110px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="height" value="0" min="0" name="height" maxlength="5" style="width:110px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" onKeyPress="return AllowOnlyNumbers(event);" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  class="act" value="0" min="0" name="act" maxlength="5" style="width:90px"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="perm" value="" name="perm" style="width:80px"/></td>
        <td class="error" style="color:red"></td><td class="errorwidth" style="color:red"></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td><input type="number" class="cartontot" value="" name="" style="width:70px" readonly/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
         <td></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="grdtot" value="" name="" style="width:80px" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Regards 
Ankit